# Angular, rxjs: HTTP Observable depending authenticated user

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have HTTP endpoint that I want to fetch in application components

```
export class ExampleService {
    public summary$: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.summary$ = this.http.get<any>('/api/summary');
    }
}
```

But result of that query depends on the currently authenticated user.
Because of that, I pipe HTTP with user$:

```
export class ExampleService {
  public summary$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private auth: AuthService) {
    this.summary$ = this.auth.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        console.log('New user');
        if (!user) {
          return of(null);
        }
        return this.http.get<any>('/api/summary');
      })
    );
  }
}
```

where `this.auth.user$` is ReplaySubject(1) of current user;

Problem is: when subscribers of summary$ going down to zero and up again (during navigation) HTTP request called again with "New user" in console.

What is the true way to cache HTTP request depending on user?

Also "do not send the request before first subscriber" is required

Comment: `ReplaySubject(1)` holds its internal no matter how many subscribers are there

Comment: Yup. And provide that value to every new subscriber, forcing HTTP request

Comment: Instead of replaySubject you should try with shareReplay operator, this cache the result after first http call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for comments. Solved with `shareReplay`.

```
export class ExampleService {
  public summary$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private auth: AuthService) {
    this.summary$ = this.auth.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (!user) {
          return of(null);
        }
        return this.http.get<any>('/api/summary');
      }),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }
}
```